# Different between Angular Component and CDK

Tags: angular, components, angular-cdk

What's the different between Angular Material [Components](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) and [CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/categories). I'm new in angular frontend development and try to implement view stuff. I found for example the *Dialog* or the *Menu* as Component or CDK in Angular.

What is the different of this two things? As far as I understand, the CDK is the newer on and more customizable? (https://blog.angular.io/a-component-dev-kit-for-angular-9f06e3b4b3b4) But in general it is a personal flavor which should be used? Or is there and *Pro* or *Cons* for one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is less about Angular itself, it is about the component library "Angular Material".
Like your linked blog post says, it is a component dev kit which provides you with predefined Angular Services, Directives, Interfaces.. you can use to develop your own component(-library). The components you linked are the ready-to-use components written and obtained by the Angular Material team. They are developed with this CDK.
As a beginner use the [Getting started Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) which shows you how to use the ready-to-use components of angular material.